# How to serialize DataTable to Xml in WCF REST services?

Tags: wcf, rest, serialization, datatable, xml-serialization

I have data layer class, some methods of this class is return DataTable. I what use this data layer class in WCF REST service. I have a problem with serialization DataTable. How to serialize DataTable to nice readable XML.
For example like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfOrderDetailsItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OrderDetailsItem>
        <OrderDetailSubId>28170892</OrderDetailSubId>
        <OrderedQuantity>1</OrderedQuantity>
        <DateAdd>2011-11-22T11:48:29.17</DateAdd>
    </OrderDetailsItem>
    <OrderDetailsItem>
        <OrderDetailSubId>28170893</OrderDetailSubId>
        <OrderedQuantity>30</OrderedQuantity>
        <DateAdd>2011-11-22T11:48:29.15</DateAdd>
    </OrderDetailsItem>
    <OrderDetailsItem>
        <OrderDetailSubId>28170894</OrderDetailSubId>
        <OrderedQuantity>22</OrderedQuantity>
        <DateAdd>2011-11-22T11:48:29.13</DateAdd>
    </OrderDetailsItem>
</ArrayOfOrderDetailsItem>
```

How to make this without mapping DataTable to other class or structure?

Answer (score 0):

Nice example about `DataTable to XML`

[Exporting a DataTable to XML and CSV](http://madskristensen.net/post/Export-a-DataTable-to-XML-and-CSV.aspx)